# Horizontally scale .Net framework System.Web.WebSockets using redis

Tags: c#, websocket, redis

I have a C# .Net framework 4.6.1 MVC application and I am using plain websockets for broadcasting messages to the connected clients. There is a limitation that I need to support .Net framework as well as .Net core clients. Hence, I have to choose plain websockets instead of SignalR.

I have created a websocket server as given on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25672569) link and a client as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63574016)

It's working absolutely fine but now the problem is to scale this application. My application uses **load balanced webfarm** architecture with **redis** cache. I found several links having theories of scaling websockets using redis or other backplane, however, I couldn't find any such example with C#.

Does anyone has any example or any direction to start scaling websockets horizontally with redis using C#?